Genotypes that are inherited linked
I am interested in whether it is possible to determine the proportions of individual genotypes of offspring from the phenotypes, and thereby the proportions of individual genotypes of gametes for two traits on a chromosome that are inherited linked (on the same chromosome).
If B represents color (B → purple, b → red) and P represents fruit shape (P → elongated, p → round), and the phenotypes are as follows:
1405 purple and elongated fruit,
95 purple and round fruit,
95 red and elongated fruit,
405 red and round fruit.
The red and round fruit traits are recessive, while purple and elongated fruit are dominant traits. We crossed two heterozygotes for both traits (i.e., we crossed an individual BbPp with BbPp) that are inherited linked. I am interested in the proportion of all genotypes in the offspring and the proportion of genotypes in the gametes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is simple Mendelian inheritance. You should be able to draw a Punnett square for this.

is this from school? it reads like a test problem. See the homework policy for some suggestions.
